# How to distinguish between deployment environments in Jenkins' pipeline script

Tags: jenkins

I use Jenkins to deploy microservices to different environments (Dev1, dev2, QA ... Prod)

I have an almost identical pipeline script for each environment, with environment name embedded in the job name, so that we do something like this to create environment specific code and variables thus keeping more code refactored to common libraries

```
    if (env.JOB_BASE_NAME.startsWith('dev1')) {
        env.ACR_TAG='dev1'
        // other settings... 
    }
    else if (env.JOB_BASE_NAME.startsWith('dev2')) {
        env.ACR_TAG='dev2'
    }
    else if (env.JOB_BASE_NAME.startsWith('qa1')) {
        env.ACR_TAG='qa1'
    }
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this, without embedding the env name in job name? I cannot use [$env.BRANCH_NAME](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples/blob/master/docs/BEST_PRACTICES.md) method

here is how my setup looks like :

DEV1 (view)

- dev1_microserviceA (job / pipline)
- dev1_microserviceB
- ...
- dev1_microserviceX\

DEV2

- dev1_microserviceA
- dev1_microserviceB
- ...
- dev1_microserviceX
  ...

Answer (score 1):

- If you have one machine per environment you can name your nodes using their host names and use `NODE_NAME` to get their name in a `node` block.
- If you have multiple machines per environment you can set `ACR_TAG` as a custom environment variable and use it inside a `node` block as well (Manage Jenkins -> Manage Nodes -> Configure (on each node) -> Node Properties -> Tick Environment variables).
- If you manage nodes dynamically perhaps it would be better to maintain a function in a shared library to determine where you are.

Comment: I guess that would not work if I have multiple environments building on the same node right?

Comment: Oh, I haven't thought of that :) The idea behind all this is basically putting environment variables, so for multiple environments building on the same node you can insert the environment variable in your Dockerfile for example. Or if your environments are mere folders on the same machine you can place a file in each folder that tells your pipeline what environment this is, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use [parameters](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters) to define which environment to deploy to. I'm using a choice parameter for exactly your usecase. I just feed the `param.TARGET_ENV` value to a global library, which then calls Ansible.

Comment: Forgive this novice question - when a job has a parameter, i can choose to Build with parameter but need to enter the pram when I run it. Can this be automated somehow?

Comment: How exactly do you want to automate? Do you want to trigger the job from another job?

Comment: i mean, when I run the build for the job, I dont want to have to enter the parameter. I dont want this part (entering the environment name) to be a manual step... makes sense? and yes, i will want to chain jobs as well